# How do I add an OnClick event to TCustomControl?

Tags: delphi, event-handling, delphi-7, mouseevent

How do I create OnClick event?
I need help with TCustomControl.

Comment: never apologize for a valid question.  Questions are what this site is for.

Comment: See also, [How to create an event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786595/delphi-event-handling-how-to-create-own-event).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `OnClick` event is defined in `TCustomControl` already. All you have to do is to make it visible. Add the line

```
published
  property OnClick;
```

to your control and you're done!

Comment: might also be helpful to know that you can trigger the event in your Control when you want to, by calling, `click` or `if assigned(onClick) then onclick(self)` not sure which of the top of my head is 'better'

Comment: @RobRok: if you copyied the complete declaration you have in effect hidden the previous one, which will then of course no longer work. In your descendant, only add `property OnClick;`. This will only change the visibility (from public or protected to published), also known as "surfacing the property", instead of redeclaring the property.

Comment: @Christopher: If there is an `Click` or `DoClick` (which adheres more to the pattern of method naming for event triggering), always use that, especially when designing components for others to use as well. They are often virtual, meaning descendants can more easily "hook" into the event triggering. Otherwise descendants are left in limbo and have to resort to event-chaining to do something whenever the event is fired.