# A lot of movable squares in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I came up with an exercise that would allow me to better understand Delphi. It contains all the things I necessarily want to know. I'm using Graphics32 component (TRect, TPaintBox32, etc.) and Borland Delphi 7.

Exercise. Write a class Square (preferably in a different .pas file than the main form of program) which allow to draw squares (with parameters like: color, size, location on screen previously set in constructor) on the main form of program. Double click on some square should change its color for random color. When we click and hold on some square we should be able to move this square with a mouse until we release click.

The way I see it: in the main form of program I will create array of Square and then the rest will be done by methods of Square class. But I don't know if this is even possible? Drawing squares, handling clicks seem to me to be very problematic. Does the Square class need separate form (.dfm file)?

I would be very very grateful for help.

EDIT: Center of the square and its border should be in different colors. Also it would be nice to add a horizontal line in the middle of the square in a border color.

EDIT2: I don't know how to apply your hints to my program. Maybe on some code will be easier to help me.

Here I've got class Box which represents square that should be able to symulate Brown motion:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, GR32, GR32_Image, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  Box = class

  private
    speed:TTimer;
    liveTime:TTimer;
    isAlive:boolean;
    rect:TRect;
    live:integer;
  public
    //procedure PaintBox321PaintBuffer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure liveTimeTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure speedTimer(Sender: TObject);
    function color():TColor32;
    constructor Create();
  end;

implementation

  constructor Box.Create();
    var x,y:integer;
  begin
    x:=random(900); y:=random(420);
    rect:=MakeRect(x,y,x+30,y+30);
   isAlive:=true; live:=random(26)+5;

    liveTime := TTimer.Create(nil);
    speed := TTimer.Create(nil);
    liveTime.interval:=1000;
    speed.interval:=live*100;
    liveTime.OnTimer := liveTimeTimer;
    speed.OnTimer := speedTimer;
  end;

  {
  procedure Box.PaintBox321PaintBuffer(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    if isAlive then begin
      PaintBox321.Buffer.Clear(Color32(255,255,255,125));
      PaintBox321.Buffer.FillRectS(rect, color());
    end;
  end;
  }

  procedure Box.liveTimeTimer(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    if isAlive then begin
      live:=live-1;
      if live=0 then isAlive:=false;
    end;
  end;

  procedure Box.speedTimer(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    if isAlive then begin
      OffsetRect(rect, 3*(random(3)-1), 3*(random(3)-1));
      speed.interval:=live*100;
      //PaintBox321.Repaint;
    end;
  end;

  function Box.color():TColor32;
  begin
    color:=Color32(255-live*5,255-live*5,255-live*5,125);
  end;
end.
```

And the main form code:
    unit Unit1;

```
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, GR32, GR32_Image, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PaintBox321: TPaintBox32;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PaintBox321PaintBuffer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1:TForm1;
  Boxes:array of Box;
  BoxesNumber:integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  randomize;
  BoxesNumber:=-1;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox321PaintBuffer(Sender: TObject);  
begin
  PaintBox321.Buffer.Clear(Color32(255,255,255,125));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BoxesNumber:=BoxesNumber+1;
  SetLength(Boxes, BoxesNumber+1);
  Boxes[BoxesNumber]:=Box.Create();
end;

end.
```

Please, read it, it's very simple. I commented fragments responsible for drawing, which I don't know how to code. I really want to know how apply here handling clicks and drawing boxes.

Comment: No, this is not at all particularly difficult. In fact, I have done similar things several times before. However, it is a bit difficult to help you much without writing the entire program for you... And for your particular question: No, that PAS file should not have a form associated with it.

Comment: Andreas, I didn't know how best to write this question. I don't want the finished program (although the analysis could also be instructive). The main problem for me is how to handle clicks and drawing square in PAS file with Square class. How this should be organised. So the best help will be several samples with these methods.

Comment: I don't know what construction will work. On the main form it is much easier. I drop something on form and double click. Then I can edit code. But I want to write class that can handle clicks, drawing and other stuff alone. This class is separated from the main form of the program and I don't know how can I realise these methods..

Comment: can anybody help? I added code ..

Answer (score 6):

A few suggestions to get you started:

- Ask yourself what kind of control you need for the square. A little knowledge of the VCL is required for answering, but consider the most obvious control and ctrl-click in the editor to find a matching ancestor that would do the trick. (Hint: `TShape` does the painting already, but I wouldn't use it.)
- You are right that with *array of Square and then the rest will be done by methods of Square class*.
- No, the `TSquare` class does not need any awareness of a form, nor should it be one. Assigning the parent of such a square will do the trick.
- All controls (i.e. ancestors of the TControl class) support mouse events/handling. (Hint: override `MouseMove` and `DblClick`.)
- You do not necessarily need the Graphics32 library.
- Although your `TSquare` class doesn't need to be registered as component, I strongly advise to (partially) read the *Component Writer's Guide* in the Delphi help.

Comment: If you want to make really smooth and nice graphics (2D or 3D), I would recommend OpenGL. OpenGL is very easy to use in Delphi, thanks to the `OpenGL` unit. Even for rather simple rendering needs, I also find OpenGL to be easier than GDI. And, of course, the result is superior.

Comment: If you're trying to learn Delphi, I don't think you should start with OpenGL. Graphics32 is way more Delphi-ish, and therefore a better way to get to know how stuff is done in Delphi. You can step through every line of code with G32, while OpenGL is largely a black box.

Comment: I would recommend GDI+, which is an object-oriented layer on top of GDI and makes it easier to work with.  There is an excellent Delphi GDI+ wrapper at http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml

Answer (score 1):

ok, because it seems that you are a beginner, this is how you can draw rectangles(squares)

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/Rectangle_%28Delphi%29

how to move it

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/OnMouseMove_%28Delphi%29

This is the start, I do not believe you should reinvent the wheel, when you have classes that can do this for you. Instead, you can study the comportment of these classes already defined.

Start with graphics in Delphi - http://delphi.about.com/od/graphics/Delphi_Graphics_Programming.htm.

I also suggest you the Embarcadero wiki, or other beginner materials in order to get the basics (what is a dfm file, etc)

Because it seems that your big issue is how to create events this question may help you
[Delphi event handling, how to create own event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786595/delphi-event-handling-how-to-create-own-event)