# Checking the items checked in a CheckListBox

Tags: delphi

As my first instance of the question was too broad, I am going to try and reword this so it is more understandable.

I want to be able to change the visibility of a label based on an item in a check box list being checked. I have a loop that goes through my check box list.

```
procedure TFrmSettings.CheckBoxSelected;
var
i : Integer;
begin
for i := 0 to CblRequiredFields.Items.Count - 1 do
 begin
 if CblRequiredFields.Checked[i] then
  begin
  FrmVReg.ReqFields(CblRequiredFields.Items.Strings[i]);
  end;
 end;
end;
```

Here is just a part of the ReqFields procedure as it would be too long to put into this Q.

```
procedure TFrmVReg.ReqFields(ChkStr : String);
begin
if ChkStr = 'Gender' then
 begin
 lblGenderReq.Visible := True;
 end
else
 begin
 lblGenderReq.Visible := False;
 end;
```

The problem I keep having is I can either only have one label active at one time or have it where a label will not disappear when it is deselected.

I hope I have reworded this to a point that it isn't as broad as the previous question.

Comment: There are so many ways you could manage this.  As it stands, this question is much too broad.  You are asking half a dozen questions here - How do I change the visibility of a control? How do I persist setting data? How do I signal a change in setting data?  How do I react to a change in setting data? Etc.  I think you're probably getting ahead of yourself here.  First think about how you want to store this setting data.  Presumably you don't want to go get your manager to reconfigure the application every time it quits and restarts?  Do you have a plan to manage that?

Comment: Okay, apologies for putting so much into this question. This system is built to be a 24/7 running system so for it to quit and restart has not yet been considered as it is not expected to. In terms of the questions you have mentioned I know how to do them, the main problem I am currently having with this system is having the items being visible at the correct times. With my attempts at it I have had a loop go around the check group and return a variable to the RegForm to activate the asterisk.

Comment: The problem is I can either only have one visible at a time and switch between or if it becomes visible it wont go away and stays there even if it isnt selected. Sorry for not making this clearer in the initial question

Comment: You probably need to rethink the architecture completely.  Consider wrapping your settings in an object.  That object should have the ability to load from and save to a file.  It should probably also provide events that are called when settings change.  Your main form can subscribe to these events and update its interface when they change. Your settings form should operate on this object (or against an interface to this object) and when changes are made your main form will then be notified.

Comment: I would guess that a subset of those things you don't know how to do.  It's important to break the problem down into sub-problems - then ask specific questions where you get stuck.  I would probably start with designing a settings object - see where that takes you.

Comment: Your edit makes this a better question.  It is clear where your error is now, but although we can "fix" this code to make it work, it is still better that you abandon this approach altogether.  You have no data store here; you are using user interface controls to hold information - don't do that.  Your forms are accessing each other directly through global variables - this will only lead to headache.  The UI should be the last thing you design, not the first.  You're trying to build an interface here on a data model that simply does not exist.

Comment: What I was doing before my edit was using an underlying database that I am using for this system I have made a table full of Yes/No fields to store the values of the checkboxes and read it from there rather than to throw variables around from different forms. Do you have a suggestion on how I can integrate it that way?

Comment: Sure - that sounds a lot better.  Have your settings form write the values out to the database.  When it makes a change, have it notify the main form.  Have the main form read from the database and update its UI.  See, perhaps : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5786595/327083

Answer (score 0):

If the `FrmVReg` form exists before the creation of the `FrmSettings` you can maintain a lisk of key-value pairs (checbox name and label object) in the `CblRequiredFields` list directly.

The labels visibility can be synchronized with the `CblRequiredFields`checks using the [`OnClickCheck`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.CheckLst.TCheckListBox.OnClickCheck) event of the `TCheckListBox` object.

```
procedure TFrmSettings.CblRequiredFieldsClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TLabel(CblRequiredFields.Items.Objects[CblRequiredFields.ItemIndex]).Visible := CblRequiredFields.Checked[CblRequiredFields.ItemIndex];
end;

procedure TFrmSettings.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CblRequiredFields.AddItem('Gender', FrmVReg.lblGenderReq);
  CblRequiredFields.AddItem('Age', FrmVReg.lblAgeReq);
  . . .
end;
```

---

If the above can't be applied, you can modify the `ReqFields` method like this:

```
procedure TFrmVReg.ReqFields(ChkStr: String; Checked: Boolean);
begin
   if ChkStr = 'Gender' then
     lblGenderReq.Visible := Checked
   else if ChkStr = 'Age' then
     lblAgeReq.Visible := Checked
   //else if . . .
end;
```

... calling it accordingly with its new signature:

```
for i := 0 to CblRequiredFields.Items.Count - 1 do
  FrmVReg.ReqFields(CblRequiredFields.Items.Strings[i], CblRequiredFields.Checked[i]);
```