# Free Pascal / Lazarus : Why is the "FormCloseQuery" Event not called in my example?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I wrote a small testprogram to try out the FormCreate and the FormCloseQuery procedure. The FormCreate works fine, but the FormCloseQuery just doesn't want to execute. Did I overlook something? Pressing the "X" on a form-window or using the close method, both doesn't work!

```
procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: boolean);
(...)


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
  beginn
  //gets executed without problems
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
  begin

  case MessageDlg('Question', mtConfirmation, [mbyes, mbno, mbcancel], 0) of

  mrYes:
  begin
    ShowMessage('yes');
    CanClose := true;
    end;

  mrNo:
  begin
    ShowMessage('no');
    CanClose := true;
    end;

  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('cancel');
    CanClose := true;
    end;

  end;
  end;
```

Here's the full code:

The lpr-File:

```
program project1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Interfaces, // this includes the LCL widgetset
  Forms, Unit1
  { you can add units after this };

{$R *.res}

begin
  RequireDerivedFormResource:=True;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

The Unit-File:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: boolean);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('FormCreate Procedure wurde gestartet');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin

  case MessageDlg('Question', mtConfirmation, [mbyes, mbno, mbcancel], 0) of

  mrYes:
  begin
    ShowMessage('yes');
    CanClose := true;
    end;

  mrNo:
  begin
    ShowMessage('no');
    CanClose := true;
    end;

  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('cancel');
    CanClose := true;
    end;

  end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: Do you set event `OnCloseQuery` with `FormCloseQuery` on object inspector?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara no, I didn't...  thanks a lot!! That did the trick. Two hours of looking, but none of the examples I found talked about that :S

Comment: I didn't know that I have to "bind" it in the object inspector. Just out of curiosity, where does the "binding" take place, or in other words, which lines code does Lazarus add and where when I select my procedure in the object inspector?

I found the following explanation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786595/delphi-event-handling-how-to-create-own-event) (which I have to work though yet). Am I on the right track here, or do I have to look for s.th. else?

Comment: What you do with form using drag and drop such edit using object inspector is stored in LFM file. Open with text editor to view its content.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara Thanks, I will give it a try! If I don't understand it, I'll start a new question, since this is getting a little off topic... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is/was to hook up the form's OnCloseQuery event of the form to this procedure. Here's a short description how to do it:

- Bring up and select the form (in my case "Form1: TForm1") in the object inspector (see explanation below).
- In the object inspector go to the tab "events"
- Locate the "OnCloseQuery"-Event and select "FormCloseQuery" if you already declared and written the procedure as it was the case in my example. (If you haven't declared/implemented it double click in the dropdown box or click on the button next to it, the one with the three dots, an an empty "OnCloseQuery"-procedure procedure will be added automatically. The code editor will jump directly to the new procedure.)

To bring up / select the form in the object inspector, open the object inspector (F11). If you are looking at the code editor bring up the form first (F12) and click on it. This should bring it up in the object inspector. Make sure the form (the top element in the list) is selected and none of it's components (like buttons etc.).

Here's another explanation: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/b2/444056.html